# SMS to server service

Tags: service, sms

I need to find a service that will allow me to send and receive SMS on a server for a project. The project requires that a user will have up to 8 keyword options to send, and will receive a different response back based on the keyword that they enter. Does anyone know of services that I could look into that will allow this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Full disclosure: I work for Twilio.

Twilio, or a similar service, will let you do this. If you can handle a form POST, you can work with Twilio: http://www.twilio.com/sms

Answer (score 0):

www.openmarket.com